# Why will an index out of range be returned?

Tags: python

I'm doing vote counting. When there is a tie, a random candidate's index(0,1,2 here) will be return. But when I tested this, index 4 and 5 returned but I think they were not in the range(0,len(candidates)-1)?

```
def countVotes(votesList,candidates):
 newList = [0]*len(candidates)
 for i in range(len(votesList)):
    candidate = votesList[i]
    candidateIndex = candidates.index(candidate)
    newList[candidateIndex] = newList[candidateIndex] + 1
 return newList

def areAllEqual(voteCounts):
 begin = voteCounts[0]
 i = 1
 while voteCounts[i] != begin:
    return False
    i = i + 1
 return True

def simpleMajority(candidates, choice1):
 voteCounts = countVotes(choice1, candidates)
 equalOrNot = areAllEqual(voteCounts)
 if equalOrNot ==True:
    winnerIndex = random.randint(0,len(candidates)-1)
    return winnerIndex

candidates = ["a","b","c"]
choice1 = ["a","b","c","a","b","c"]
result = simpleMajority(choice1, candidates)
print(result)
```

Comment: Any reason why you flip the names of the argument here, compared to the function definition? `result = simpleMajority(choice1, candidates)`

Comment: Also, in the function `areAllEqual`,I don't think the increment works, as you are returning False even before incrementing

Comment: Just realized that arguments are flipped. So problem solved. Thx!

Comment: cmon always thre last one to answer: result = simpleMajority(candidates, choice1)

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG I don't think I need the increment  if the first two elements are different. Only if the first two are same I need to check the following, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have interchanged the values passing as the parameter., thus, you get undesired output.

```
choice1 = ["a","b","c","a","b","c"]
result = simpleMajority(candidates, choice1)
print(result)
```